# ASP.NET time not formatting properly

Tags: asp.net, time, format

I have been wrestling with this stupid repeater all night long. I can get the *Dates* to format properly by using `<%#Eval("Start Date", "{0:MMM dd, yyyy}") %>`, but using 
`<#Eval("Start Time", "{0:t}") %>` is **NOT** producing the right time. No matter what kind of formatting I use, it still comes out as "hh:mm:ss" in military time format.

I have tried hard-coding globalization settings into the web.config file. I have tried every combination of formatting symbols the internet has to offer, but no matter what I do, it still comes out "15:45:00"

HOW can I get this stupid thing to spit out "3:45 PM" instead of "15:45:00"!? I'm at my wit's end.

I have tried:
`<%# Eval("Start Time")%>`
`<%# Eval("Start Time", {0:t}") %>`
`<%# Eval("Start Time", {0:T}") %>`
`<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "End Time", "{0:t}") %>`
`<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "End Time", "{0:T}") %>`
...Nothing ever changes.

Comment: Your frustration is not a reason for the language

Comment: What data type is the `Start Time` field?

Comment: Have you tried converting the field to a DateTime? <%# String.Format("{0:t}", Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("Start Time"))) %> -- obviously need to add a check for null, etc.

Answer (score 7):

To format a TimeSpan in hh:mm style, **Bind** needs non-escaped format and **Eval** needs an escaped format.

```
Text='<%# Bind("start_time","{0:h\:mm tt}") %>'
and
Text='<%# Eval("start_time",@"{0:h\:mm tt}") %>'
```

[Here](http://csharpin.blogspot.com/2011/06/working-with-time-type-in-sql-and-asp.html) I wrote more about this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String.Format("{0:h\:mm tt}", Container.DataItem);
```